# Reportlab pdfgen support for bold truetype fonts

Tags: django, pdf-generation, truetype, reportlab

I have been using reportlab pdfgen to create dynamic pdf documents for printing. It has been working very well for a number of years.

We are having a fund raising event coming up, and wish to generate pdf receipts with the 'theme' font we are using (specifically talldeco.ttf).

I have set the font no problem using the following:

```
        from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics 
        from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont 
        ttfFile = "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-tall-deco/TALLDECO.TTF"
        pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont("TallDeco", ttfFile))
        p.setFont("TallDeco", 18) # Was Times-Bold...
```

Now comes the issue: some of the text needs to be bold and italics, and the talldeco just comes with 1 file (unlike some of the other fonts). I can bold and italicize text in this font in openoffice.

Per the reportlab users guide (http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/rl-toolkit/guide/) page 53, it should be possible and they show some code and the results, but our software is using drawString calls instead of paragraphs. A test app based on the sample noted above:

```
        from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics 
        from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont 
        from reportlab.pdfbase.pdfmetrics import registerFontFamily
        ttfFile = "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-tall-deco/TALLDECO.TTF"
        pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont("TallDeco", ttfFile))
        registerFontFamily('TallDeco',normal='TallDeco',bold='TallDeco-Bold',italic='TallDeco-Italic',boldItalic='TallDeco-BoldItalic')
        p.setFont("TallDeco-Bold", 18) # Was Times-Bold...
```

Just gives a Key Error on 'TallDeco-Bold'.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

TTFont has a `subfontIndex` parameter.

The following works for me (using reportlab 3.0 on OS X):

```
menlo_path = "/System/Library/Fonts/Menlo.ttc"
pdfmetrics.registerFont(ttfonts.TTFont("Menlo", menlo_path,
                                       subfontIndex=0))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(ttfonts.TTFont("Menlo-Bold", menlo_path,
                                       subfontIndex=1))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(ttfonts.TTFont("Menlo-Italic", menlo_path,
                                       subfontIndex=2))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(ttfonts.TTFont("Menlo-BoldItalic", menlo_path,
                                       subfontIndex=3))
pdfmetrics.registerFontFamily("Menlo", normal="Menlo", bold="Menlo-Bold",
                              italic="Menlo-Italic",
                              boldItalic="Menlo-boldItalic")
```

Comment: Even though it doesn't solve the original question, this method worked for me when using Consolas which does include the style variations as separate files.

Comment: It looks to me that this does not answer the Q that the OP had. His Q has to do with a single TTF file. The answer given here makes explicit reference to a TTC file.

Answer (score -1):

The bold, italic and boldItalic fonts need to be defined.

```
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont("TallDeco-Bold", ttfFile))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont("TallDeco-Italic", ttfFile))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont("TallDeco-BoldItalic", ttfFile))
```

But because they all point to the same **ttfFile** the output will all look like the default TallDeco i.e. no bold or italic

Comment: This isn't any solution and depend on ttf file it might even end with errors like `redefining named object: 'toUnicodeCMap:AAAAAA+Font'`