# Python ReportLab pdfgen web fonts support: WOFF type

Tags: python, pdf-generation, webfonts, reportlab

Reportlab apparently officially supports TTF, per: [Reportlab pdfgen support for bold truetype fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370630/reportlab-pdfgen-support-for-bold-truetype-fonts)

Has anyone had experience with it supporting webfonts in any way? I have a WOFF file, but there may be other options.

Comment: I have had no luck with web fonts but lots of success with TTF's.